# Odoo 8, Pull and Push rules managment

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, warehouse

I have main warehouse with bar-code scanners
i have these statues

1-when receiving raw materials this steps should be done with bar-code scanner

A-Receiving B-Inspection C-Put Away(in stock)

2-when our branches request raw materials (raw materials always available in warehouse)

A-Picking(from stock) B-Packing C-Dispatching

there is also a POS per branch that should sell pizza
and the pizza has of course raw materials

so, can you guys help me with an example for the above situation how to manage routes,push and pull rules and defining warehouse with location
keeping in mind we have 41 branch and 1 warehouse

Second how to reduce raw materials upon selling pizza from current branch stock
and not sell pizza if stock does not have enough required raw materials

Thank You in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In odoo v8 you can Have to first Activate configuration the advance Route. and then you can define the push-pull rule accordingly.

So,

> **step 1  Activate configuration the advance Route.**

To Make such the setting you can go to the

> **Setting -> Warehouse-> Logistic & Warehouse and checkmark Manage advance Routes for your warehouse.**

[image: Warehouse-setting-v8]

> Step 2 Define the Push and pull rule.

To define the Push and pull rule you can go to 
**Warehouse ->  configuration ->  routs**

[image: PushRule-Pull-Rule]

For the more Example, you can check the below link

**For v9**
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/inventory/routes/concepts/use_routes.html

**For v7**

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/pull-flow-and-push-flow-of-a-product-6888

Comment: I'm sorry but you did not help at all